Oracle Database: Required System Groups on Linux
I'm wondering if it's necessary to create the following system groups (Linux) for Oracle Database 12c/19c+ installation to works properly:
54322(dba), 54323(oper), 54324(backupdba), 54325(dgdba), 54326(kmdba), 54330(racdba)
I've always just created one group: oinstall and assigned the oracle user to it:
[root@lab1srv ~]# id oracle
uid=1000(oracle) gid=1001(oinstall) groups=1001(oinstall)

During database binaries installation I've always assigned oinstall group like below:

and eveything works correctly.
I've never noticed any problems with the database in my test and production environments.
However, according to the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/database-installation-guide-linux.pdf (page 100), it seems like these groups should be created and assigned to oracle user.
What's more, the database preinstall rpm package also creates these groups. (previously, I've always configured OS manually without preinstall rpm)
But are they actually necessary?
Please clarify me, thank you in advance.

The groups is typically to allow for organizations that have a myriad of roles (eg some people look after backups, others storage, etc) and to be able to carve out appropriate OS level access for them.
Plenty of people out there use only the 'dba' and 'oinstall' groups, the separation being to differentiate software from the database itself.
